# Panda df replace value in column with dict and regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dict which is as follows:

```
MyDict = {
'Type': 'D',
'Tariff': 'T2',
'Profile' : 1,
'QuoteType' : 'Firm'
    }
```

I have a df which looks like this
[image]

edit:
Providing you a dict which can be converted in df to reproduce:

```
dictdf = [{'Criteria1': '', 'Criteria2': ''},
        {'Criteria1': '', 'Criteria2': ''},
        {'Criteria1': "@Tariff in ['T4', 'T5']", 'Criteria2': "@QuoteType == 'Quote'"},
        {'Criteria1': "@Tariff in ['T1', 'T2', 'T3']", 'Criteria2': "@QuoteType == 'Quote'"},
        {'Criteria1': "@Type == 'D' and @Profile not in [1, 2]", 'Criteria2': "@QuoteType == 'Quote'"},
        {'Criteria1': "@Type == 'D'", 'Criteria2': "@QuoteType == 'Quote'"},
        {'Criteria1': "@Tariff in ['T1', 'T2', 'T3']", 'Criteria2': "@QuoteType == 'Quote'"},
        {'Criteria1': "@Tariff == 'T4'", 'Criteria2' : ''},
        {'Criteria1': "@Tariff == 'T5'", 'Criteria2': ''},
        {'Criteria1': "@Tariff in ['T1', 'T2', 'T3']", 'Criteria2': ''}
       ]
pd.DataFrame(dictdf)
```

My goal is first to replace the @xxx with their corresponding value in the dict. Then I'd like to evaluate the Criteria

Thefore, with the dict I've provided, I expect `df[2, 'Criteria1'] = ('D' == 'D')` (having replaced the @Type by its value in the dict), and then when I evaluate it I get `True`
for the next [3, 'Criteria1'], I want `'T2' in ['T4', 'T5']` (having replaced 
@Tariff by its value in MyDict) which gives False

```
df[3, 'Criteria1'] = eval ('T2' in ['T4','T5']) = False
```

etc

I've found panda replace but I'm not very at ease with regex and I'm not sure how I should evaluate the value for all row. I could do it with pd.apply but I've read many times that this is to ban as much as possible hence me reaching to get an optimized way of doing so ?

Evaluating those criteria the most efficiently is critical for my needs as it is the most important process my python script will do

Once this is done, I have the same question, but imagine I have an empy MyDict at the beginning. I create it as I go through every row in my df. Thefore how should I do if for instance, I know the value of Tariff only after I know the value of Type, which let's assume I know on row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irxql.png) in the df I've provided ? Is it mandatory to use a for loop ?

Comment: For starters, please replace the image of a dataframe with something that can be copied and pasted into a Python interpreter.

Comment: I've edited my post, sorry about that I will make sure next time to process this way